# Вставка изображения из picture box в word c#

Tags: c#, ms-word, picturebox

Есть picture box, в который пользователь вставляет картинку. Необходимо, при нажатии на кнопку, эту картинку сохранить в word документ. Как это сделать?

Comment: То есть, вам нужно _создать_ документ Word с контентом из данной картинки? А формат rtf подойдёт?

Comment: Предполагается, что у нас уже есть документ, в который надо вставить картинку. К сожалению, необходим именно docx формат.

Comment: С docx сложнее, вам, кажется, нужен Office Interop. То есть как бы придётся пользоваться библиотеками самого офиса. [Вот тут](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word%28v=office.11%29.aspx) по идее должна быть документация (сам не пробовал).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нашла ответ. Добавила в участок кода где работаю с вордом вот эти строчи:
`wordApp.ActiveDocument.Sections[1].                      Headers[Word.WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary].
Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture(pic);`

А в кнопке добавления картинки в picture box прописала следующее:

`private void AddPicture_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
            openFileDialog.Filter = "PNG|*.png";`

```
        if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)

            Image.ImageLocation = openFileDialog.FileName;
            Image.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;

    }
```